# MongoDB - Removing leading and trailing spaces from array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have a `users` collection in MongoDB with the following structure (I removed all irrelevant fields):

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    labels: Array <{ name: String, category: String }>
}
```

I want to remove leading and trailing spaces from the `name` property inside the `labels` array.
I tried to do this:

```
db.users.update(
  { "labels.name" : { $regex: /^\s+|\s+$/ } }, 
  [{ $set: { "labels.$[].name": { $trim: { input: "$labels.$[].name" } } } }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "message" : "write failed with error: {" +
              "    'nMatched' : 0," +
              "    'nUpserted' : 0," +
              "    'nModified' : 0," +
              "    'writeError' : {" +
              "    \t'code' : 16410," +
              "    \t'errmsg' : 'Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.'" +
              "    }" +
              "}",
    "stack" : "script:4:2"
}
```

What is the correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use aggregation operators (`$trim`) in regular update query, you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$regex` operator to pass `^` to match space from beginning and `$` to match space from end.  Note this will not pinpoint names in the `labels` array with leading or trailing space, but it will eliminate from processing any doc where *none* of the names have leading or trailing space.
- put array bracket in update part
- `$map` to iterate loop of `labels` array and trim the `name` using `$trim` operator

```
db.users.update(
  { "labels.name": { $regex: "^ | $" } },
  [{
    $set: {
      labels: {
        $map: {
          input: "$labels",
          in: {
            category: "$$this.category",
            name: { $trim: { input: "$$this.name" } }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KGQa-1wkxyh)